# Como comparar informações de uma tabela com outra tabela

Tags: r

Tenho uma planilha muito grande em formato csv com cerca de 8 milhões de linhas e diversas colunas, dentre elas uma coluna com o telefone das pessoas. 
Tenho também uma outra planilha, em excel, com 2 mil linhas com o telefone de pessoas. 
Preciso gerar uma terceira planilha, com os telefones que aparecem nas duas planilhas, simultaneamente.
Como faço isso?

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito vaga e talvez nem pertença ao StackOverflow se você pretende usar planilha pra fazer isso. Se for planilha - é Excel ou outro produto? Se quer fazer usando código - que linguagem de programação você conhece e pretende usar?

Answer (score 1):

Use a função `inner_join` do pacote `dplyr`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(nome = c("Ana", "Bernardo", "Carlos"),
                  telefone = c("123", "456", "789"),
                  altura = c(1.70, 1.75, 1.80))

##       nome telefone altura
## 1      Ana      123   1.70
## 2 Bernardo      456   1.75
## 3   Carlos      789   1.80


df2 <- data.frame(nome = c("Bernardo", "Carlos", "Daniel"),
                  telefone = c("456", "789", "555"),
                  peso = c(75, 80, 70))

##       nome telefone peso
## 1 Bernardo      456   75
## 2   Carlos      789   80
## 3   Daniel      555   70

library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = "telefone")
    nome.x telefone altura   nome.y peso
1 Bernardo      456   1.75 Bernardo   75
2   Carlos      789   1.80   Carlos   80
Warning message:
Column `telefone` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```